# Did I miss the bounty deadline and if so, is there any way of manually awarding it?

Tags: support, bounty

I set a bounty on a question and I think I may have missed the deadline.  I upvoted the answer I thought was the best, and I accepted it, but there was no thingie on the left for me to award the bounty.  Is that because I missed the deadline?  Where did the bounty go in this case, and can I award it now somehow to the following answer?  https://english.stackexchange.com/a/359033/112436

**Edit**

I don't mind the 50 points disappearing -- after all, I should have kept to the deadline-- but I wanted to give the accepted answer the bounty.  I noticed there is apparently an opportunity to open a new bounty.  Really?  I can start a new bounty, this time to reward an existing answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you may indeed set a new bounty to reward an existing answer - in fact, when you offer a bounty, this is given as one of the choices for explaining why the bounty is being given.

The only small snag is that when a second or third bounty is offered, the bounty itself needs to be (at least) double the points of the previous bounty. So, if you wanted to offer a new bounty, it would have to be for 100 rep.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I’m sorry but you’ve missed the deadline.

And because no new answer posted after the bounty was set managed to reach a score of 2, nor any new answer marked as accepted, those repubits have now all been recycled by the great repcatcher in the æther.

In response to an MSE question about [“Why aren't bounties refunded if they are not awarded?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56298), Grace, one of our community managers, answered:

> A bounty is not a guarantee. It's less risky in the new system, but it never has, nor ever will be, a guarantee for the answers you need. It's payment for a *bid for an answer*, not payment for actual answers themselves.
>
> Remember that although you didn't get an actual answer, you did get 7 days on the Featured tab. If you got refunded, then you could keep your question on the Featured tab forever, which really reduces the benefit that placing a bounty has in the first place.
>
> Basically, consider this like a parking meter - the reputation you spent is good enough for only 7 days. If you need more time, you need to spend more reputation. Of course, it's a parking meter where you can pay however much you want and get the same amount of time, but the extra payment is for the possibility of better quality attention during that same period.

Additionally, a refund request feature for [“Should bounty be returned if there is NO answer at all?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21609) was marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

So I’m afraid that’s all she wrote, as the saying goes.

Answer (score 1):

https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/272535/revisions

Yes, you missed it, and it looks like you missed the grace period too. "Bounty Ended with no winning answer by Community♦"

I think the system requires a post with at least two upvotes to automatically award the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciate your enthusiasm in following up on your original bounty I don't  think that the question or any of the answers are particularly helpful to ELU. Since it's all based on the whimsical usage of a single internet comment by a non-native speaker this question is off-topic from the get go. Unfortunately the continuous barrage of bounties blocks close voting.

If I were to coin the term *hurzel-purzel-word* the only knowledgeable person about that word is me. The same applies to the *uber-word*. Once again:

> I made up the combination uber-word, but the etymological root is of course [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cber#In_English) - [Hagen von Eitzen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/48743/hagen-von-eitzen) ([here the chat log](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23999664#23999664))

The question is essentially a request for chat analysis.

Since the original commenter did not involve him- or herself in this question we remain clueless about the precise meaning. Thankfully the accepted answer holds a disclaimer that it is full of guesswork. It had been good judgement when what's now an answer was posted as a comment and not an answer. There is no authoritative source, there are three options which are obviously guesswork.

JOSH's answer on the other hand gives detailed information about the current use of *uber* in English, yet we have no idea in which way the term *word* is supposed to be supercharged by the prefix since the current usage does not yield immediately sensible conclusions.

Long story short, I implore you to not award the bounty to any answer. In seven days we will finally be able to close the question without setting further precedents for awarding guesswork or answers that still leave one guessing.

Comment: *A "cuckoo" word that usurps all native words* was helpful for me.  I realize the contributor wasn't certain that was what the person who coined the word actually had in mind, but it was helpful for me.  That contributor wouldn't have gone to the trouble to sit down and think about my question, or write up his thoughts, if I hadn't upped the ante by setting the original bounty.  Therefore I wanted to follow through and place the award for the effort, to show my appreciation.  I'm sorry this whole question and aftermath makes you squirm.  It will be over soon.